# Counting data occurence from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the number of times for example data 'a' occurs from all the table below that from column d1,d2 and d3. For example here the number of  times 'a' occurs from the table is 3.

```
d1| d2 | d3 |
-------------
a| ab | a |
a| ab  | ab|
ab| av | ac |
zx| cx  | zz|
```

I use

```
SELECT SUM(d1='a') + SUM(d2='a') + SUM(d3='a') FROM my_table
```

and

```
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$allsum = $result[0];
echo '<pre>';
            echo $allsum;
            echo '</pre>';
```

but the echo does not work

thnk for any solutions.

Comment: what result you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT SUM(d1='a') + SUM(d2='a') + SUM(d3='a') as allsum FROM my_table



  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 


        echo $row['allsum'];
```

Comment: If you're going to reference the array with keys rather than indexes I would suggest using mysql_fetch_assoc(..) instead to increase readability.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT SUM(d1='a') + SUM(d2='a') + SUM(d3='a') FROM my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3e1d/1/0).

Comment: how do you echo that cause i use $result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$allsum = $result[0];

echo '<pre>';
            echo $allsum;
            echo '</pre>'; and it does not work

Comment: When you use mysql_fetch_assoc(..) you'll get an associative array instead of an array with 0..n indexes. Try to use print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); and you'll see the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `d1`='a' OR `d2`='a' OR `d3`='a';
```

Comment: What if a single record has the desired value in multiple columns?